# Getting SAP BOBI object with REST API after new instance creation (the report is schedule one)

Tags: node.js, rest, business-objects

SAP BOBI create -
A document with two reports within report 1 and report 2.

Report 1  and report 2 are scheduled in every 30 minutes, they will pull the data from database and updating the report, in this process it's creating a new instance.

Then if we are accessing above report in other application using REST API:

```
GET 6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/<5407>/reports/1
```

The latest data is not fetching from the report, the reason the report/documents are not physically stored after new instance creation.

It seems to be that the below put request is not saving the document.

```
PUT 6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/<5407>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting hung up on terminology.

A *report* is a tab within a WebI *document*.  A *document* can be scheduled, but you cannot schedule individual reports within a document.

When a schedule runs, it creates an *instance*, which is a copy of the original document but with updated data.  The original document is not modified.

When you call documents/5407/reports/1, you are accessing the first report tab in the original document.

To access the scheduled instances, you must use documents/5407/schedules.  This will return the ID, name, and status of each scheduled instance.  You can then retrieve the instance itself with documents/5407/schedules/x, where x is the ID of the instance.

Comment: Yes, thank you for correct my terminology.   I did  documents/5407/schedules.  it;s given  all schedules list . Then documents/5407/schedules/x,  giving instace details but to get the data using only this right REST API GET 6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/<5407>/reports/1

Comment: How to get newly create instance data?

Comment: biprws/raylight/v1/documents/x